# Does it matter that wlan0 has changed its name to eth1 after I upgraded to 12.04?

Tags: wireless

After upgrading to 12.04 I cannot see **wlan0** as ny wireless connection. It's now called **eth1**.

ifconfig and iwconfig also return the same: **eth1**.

Is this okay, or should I make any changes?

[image: screenshot]

```
$ iwconfig
ppp0    no wireless extensions.

lo      no wireless extensions.

eth1    IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated
        Link Quality:5   Signal level:0   Noise level:220
        Rx invalid nwid:0   invalid crypt:0    invald misc:0

eth0    no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: This may be the following bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/1008325

Answer (score 6):

That [bug "report"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/1008325) (more like a series of people pointing fingers without testing anything) might *apply* but it's not a udev issue.

As anybody who has followed these things for more than week will know, the Broadcom driver for some of their chips has flipped around over the years on how it names things... But it's just a name. You probably could force it back to being an `wlan*` device but only with a fight.

I'd just ignore it and do something awesome instead. Network manager should still be able to use it as a wireless device, it should all still work.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo brctl addbr br0

sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0

sudo brctl addif br0 eth0

sudo ifconfig br0 192.168.1.115 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 br0

sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 br0
```

btw what do you got with wlan0 ? do there any network came across ? or its just unplugged ?

Comment: Can you answer it more elobrately? i did not understand anything.! :(