# Wlan-Card named 'eth1'?

Tags: wireless, networking

My Wlan-Card is named as 'eth1'. Last week it was wlan0 and now it turned to eth. I don't know why and don't know how to change this. How can I change this back?

Comment: did you recently upgrade your ubuntu version to 12.04 or newer?

Comment: m facing the same problem after upgrading to 12.04-http://askubuntu.com/q/139462/46000

Comment: Do you need to change it back to eth0? It should work correctly as eth1 too.

Comment: what manufacturer of wireless card is it?

Comment: No I haven't upgraded my ubuntu. It is the same state as the installation. And I want to change it back to wlan0. It is a Broadcom Card in an Acer laptop and named Acer Nplify (TM) 802.11 b/g/n

Answer (score 2):

The names are determined by the udev rules in the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. You can change the name there.

I don't know why that file changed on your computer, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the following bug: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/1008325

However, I suspect that was changed intentionally by the ubuntu maintainers for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the line for your wlan card in

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net
```

Probably the last line, check with

```
lspci | grep -i net
```

And reboot